# Unity themes that use different colors for each window

Tags: themes, window

The title says it all really. I'm looking for an Ubuntu theme that will use different colors  or at least different shades of one color for the different windows that I have open.

i installed [Paper](http://samuelhewitt.com/paper) but all the windows are same grey color..

are there any working  versions of paper or perhaps other things that use different colored windows?